# Apache 2.4 Error: FCGI: attempt to connect to Unix domain socket /run/php/php7.0-fpm.sock (*) failed

Tags: php, apache

I have updated my working Froxlor installation to PHP 7. 
All my customer-sites work perfectly fine (with PHP 7 via FPM).

The only problem is, that if I want to access the Froxlor Backend, I get an Erorr 503. 
The apache Error-Log says:

```
`[Tue Oct 11 10:01:04.067069 2016] [proxy:error] [pid 23949] (2)No such file or directory: AH02454: FCGI: attempt to connect to Unix domain socket /run/php/php7.0-fpm.sock (*) failed`
`[Tue Oct 11 10:01:04.089648 2016] [proxy_fcgi:error] [pid 23949] [client xx.xx.xx.xx:1819] AH01079: failed to make connection to backend: httpd-UDS`
```

The Error-Log of PHP-FPM says nothing.

The same thing happens, if I try to access the server directly via IP.

System-Details:

- Debian 8
- Apache 2.4
- PHP7
- PHP7-FPM

Where I have to serach for the Problem? If needed, config-files can be provided.

Comment: This could be a file permission issue with those certificate files.

Comment: In this folder are a lot of .crt-Files, all have the same permissions (600), owner is root, and the cron did not complain about the others. The other (working) sites are served via HTTPS.

Comment: Then you will have to check what that script actually attempts.

Comment: Got rid of the Error in the cron. The error 503 and the error in the Apache-Log is not solved yet.

Answer (score 23):

If you are using **PHP-FPM**, the problem may also be that you need to start the PHP service.

> Apache does not automatically stop the process, so you will either manually start it up or automatically on startup

For PHP 7.x (remember to include your version):

```
service php7.x-fpm start
```

For PHP 7:

```
service php7-fpm start
```

For PHP 5:

```
service php-fpm start
```

This will begin the FPM process for you.

Additionally, you may also want the process to startup on boot. To do that simply enter the following, of course considering your respective version.

```
systemctl enable php7.x-fpm
```

Answer (score 5):

I had same issue, on New server having `php7.4` and these virtual host configuration files(located in `/etc/apache2/sites-available/` directory) i migrated from server having `php7.2`.

When checked in detail i found

```
<FilesMatch \.php$>
     SetHandler "proxy:unix:/run/php/php7.2-fpm.sock|fcgi://localhost/"
</FilesMatch>
```

Which then i replaced with

```
<FilesMatch \.php$>
     SetHandler "proxy:unix:/run/php/php7.4-fpm.sock|fcgi://localhost/"
</FilesMatch>
```

Basically updating php version and it worked fine after restarting `apache2`

Comment: typo in the `/etc/apache2/sites-avaialable/` but that is ok

Comment: thanks @BhavinRana people may just copy paste and find error. let me correct it.

Answer (score 1):

Steps I made in order to make it work on my host:

in `/etc/apt/sources.list` - added `non-free` to debian repository

```
apt update
apt install libapache2-mod-fastcgi
a2enmod fastcgi
```

(That made the "Invalid command 'FastCgiExternalServer' error, I encountered on a new installation", go away).

In Froxlor - "Settings" - "Froxlor VirtualHost settings":
[X] Enable PHP-FPM for the Froxlor vHost If enabled, Froxlor will also be running under a local user.

I also removed all "Listen" entries from apache2's `ports.conf`

Answer (score 0):

I upgraded the Ubuntu distribution on my DigitalOcean server from 20.04 to 22.04.  My server was running on PHP 7.4, after upgrade I discovered that php was updated to 8.1 automatically the Apache server was still configured to use PHP 7.4 FPM.  The following commands got my website back up,

```
> sudo service php8.1-fpm start
> sudo a2enmod proxy_fcgi
> sudo a2enconf php8.1-fpm.conf
> sudo systemctl reload apache2
```

basically re-configuring apache2 to use the newly installed php8.1-fpm module